# Why is there a `Const` and a `Mean` operation in metrics node in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I try to implement a custom loss function using `tensorflow`'s `keras` interface.

I added the same function to the `loss` and to the `metrics`:

```
def one_class_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.norm(y_pred, name='distance')

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
              loss=one_class_loss,
              metrics=[one_class_loss])
```

In `TensorBoard`, I see the following as part of the network:
[image]

Why is there a `Mean` and a `Const` before the training? What do they represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Const` part is used to avoid numerical instabilities. The derivative of the sqrt is (1 / sqrt) * inner_derivative and therefore if the sqrt is 0 (e.g. minimal), the derivative will result to an `inf` value and blow up your model. However, if you add a const to the sum the derivative is 0, due to the inner_derivative being 0. In all other cases the `Const` has minimal impact on your performance.

The `Mean` is just used to make the optimizer work properly. It makes no sense to optimize a multi valued output, so the optimizer reduces your loss to a single value automatically by applying a mean operation, across the batch size, e.g. Mean Squared Error. (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/23257/gradient-descent-with-vector-valued-loss)

Comment: Is there a `keras` documentation describing this? What is usually the `Const` value? `epsilon`?

Comment: @doodoroma You can check the const value in TensorBoard, clicking on the node and looking at its properties.